# Different install speeds on usb 3.0 usbs

Tags: system-installation

I got 2 usbs from Lexar both usb 3.0 one 32gb the other 64gb. I installed Ubuntu on the 32gb one and it was a fast install. On the other 64gb one it was the slowest ever and took 2 installs to get Ubuntu working.

Is this normal or did I do something wrong with  the partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing exactly this for a few years and like you, I too purchased Lexars only to find out they are over-rated, at least it appears I'm not the only amazon purchaser who has come to this conclusion.  They just aren't very good for speed, and even after retiring them I discovered other unexpected limitations to them.  Simply having a usb3.0 interface does not make for a fast device, but even among devices claiming speed like certain Lexars, the only guidelines you can depend on are respectable reviewers and your own benchmark testing.  If you don't mind wiping those usb flashdrives, you can use a utility built into Ubuntu's "disk utility" app to benchmark them, but they have to be completely wiped with no partitions on them at all before the benchmarker will work.

By contrast the Patriot brand, ["Supersonic Rage XT"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H70ZNBC) flashdrives are far better.  They are not the fastest I've tried, which I'll come back to later, but they are probably your best value in terms of money and speed.  Recently I purchased a special model of PNY which also claims exceptional speeds.  I've simply been too busy to run the benchmark.

Now if you want REAL performance, here's what you do.  You purchase [THIS external mSATA to USB3.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I4701O6) adapter case and any size of mSATA drive you like.  Most such drives 6gb/sec transfer rates.  With this adapter you'll come close to the performance you'd see with them as internal.  I'm using one right now on this computer I'm writing to you from.  I swear to you, if you try this, you will experience performance you won't see on most gaming desktop computers.

In case you care to know, I'm using a 64gb msata in my case, but I could just as easily use one as large as 1tb.  Other advantages of this design is that if by any chance you bump your stick you can break the plug off and you are locked out but as this device uses a male to male adapter cable, the odds are highly against a cable bump leading you to being locked out.

Is should also mention the dimensions as the ad omits it.  1.75" wide, 3" long, 5/16" thick.

In case you wish to duplicate my success precisely, here's [the exact 64g mSATA SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DY5C7AY) I'm using, here's the link to the exact item.  Interesting, the price has fallen, making this method less than half again as expensive as purchasing the patriot I linked you to.

You may also be intrigued by some of the clues about this project I've posted here on my user profile and on my linkedin page.  I'm hoping to one day dedicate some sort of web or perhaps Google plus community page to it as I personally feel it is the way to go for most people.  Having portable boot media like this is actually more practical than most people can imaging.  In some ways it is more practical than cloud computing in so much as it is not dependent upon internet connectivity.